# UITableView only showing 1 cell from feed. RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, restkit

I am using RestKit to pull a news feed and it works for pulling the feed.  I have used a Master Detail view and it shows multiple feeds in the console but only displays 1 feed in the UITableView (Only 1 cell)

here is my code

```
    @interface MasterViewController (){

    NSArray *feedObjects;
    NSMutableArray *feedArray;

}

@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];
    feedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self configureRestKit];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(RKResponseDescriptor *)responseDescriptor {

    RKObjectMapping *bodyMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BaseClass class]];
    [bodyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"body",@"title"]];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:bodyMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    return responseDescriptor;
}

-(void)configureRestKit{

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlExample"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[[self responseDescriptor]]];

    [objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        feedObjects = mappingResult.array;
        [feedArray addObject:feedObjects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Feeds: %@", mappingResult.array);

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];

    [objectRequestOperation start];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return feedArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableArray *feedarray = feedArray[indexPath.row];
    BaseClass *feedO = feedarray[0];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",feedO.title];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

}
```

If anyone could help me that would be great, i've tried adding the mappingResults to a NSArray instead of NSMutableArray but this breaks the program the way i have tried.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does - you are adding only one object to your array here:

```
[feedArray addObject:feedObjects];
```

Which means that your function returning number of rows:

```
feedArray.count == 1
```

What you want to do is to add all results separately to your NSMutableArray or even use NSArray you got from response directly as data source - so you have an NSArray with only 1 depth level.

```
[feedArray addObjectsFromArray:feedObjects]
```

Actually in your case I don't see a reason to keep both feedObjects and feedArray, you can throw away feedArray and use feedObjects instead everywhere.

Comment: i now have all the feed objects stored but they still won't show in the UITableView?

Comment: It's working thankyou.  I didn't need to add Objects.  Just set feedObjects = mappingResults.array